# Unauthorized request Mollie Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mollie

I'm trying to use Mollie in Laravel, but I'm encountering problems.
This is my code (token from the Laravel/Mollie Github page):

```
public function payApi($amount, $email) {
    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->create([
        'amount' => $amount,
        'description' => $email,
        'redirectUrl' => 'http://google.com',
    ]);

    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->get($payment->id);

    if ($payment->isPaid()) {
        echo "Payment received";
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Mollie_API_Exception in Base.php line 353: Error executing API call (request): Unauthorized request
```

I guess this is because I need to set the API test-key, but I don't know how to do that in Laravel-Mollie, it is documented for standard Mollie though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [README.md](https://github.com/mollie/laravel-mollie), you need to connect Mollie to Laravel Socialite first. If you intend on using Mollie Connect, update `config/services.php` by adding this to the array:

```
'mollie' => [
    'client_id' => env('MOLLIE_CLIENT_ID', 'app_xxx'),
    'client_secret' => env('MOLLIE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('MOLLIE_REDIRECT_URI'),
],
```

And add your test-key in config/mollie.php.

Comment: Now I'm getting thus error: Unable to communicate with Mollie (28): Resolving timed out after 10519 milliseconds. Do I need to replace the env(VALUES) with something?

Comment: @O'Niel No, this is not required. Just go through the rest of the readme and check that you haven't forgot something!

Comment: I had to add the test key to config/mollie.php as well. Thanks!!! But now I'm getting a blank page, what now?

Comment: @O'Niel You are welcome! Check your error log ;) This can have multiple reasons.